# How to make ViewChild to set a property instead of a variable

Tags: angular, viewchild

I have a Class. And a property of this Class is named model_number. What I'm trying to do here is to set an attribute "DOMelement" of this property with the ViewChild.

**The code :**

```
import {Component,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-form',
    templateUrl: './form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss']
})
export class FormComponent  {
    @ViewChild('model_number') model_number.DOMelement:ElementRef;
    model_number = {value: '', api_name: 'hardware_model_number', required: true,element:{}};
}
```

But it fails to compile with a nice **syntax error.** How can I achieve this :

```
 @ViewChild('model_number') model_number.DOMelement:ElementRef;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, but it feels excessive if someone finds another way I'm all ears.

here is my take on this problem :

```
import {Component,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-form',
    templateUrl: './form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss']
})
export class FormComponent  implements AfterViewInit{
    @ViewChild('model_number') model_number_DE:ElementRef;

    model_number = {value: '', api_name: 'hardware_model_number', required: true,element:{}};
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.model_number.element = this.model_number_DE.nativeElement;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ViewChild('model_number') model_number:ElementRef;
```

And in your code

```
this.model_number.nativeElement
```

Comment: I don't want to duplicate my variables. I just want to put the result of viewChild inside "model_number.DOMelement" and not just in model_number. Is there a way to do this ?